# Encapsulate the output of invoke command in a variable - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables, scripting, invoke-command, storing-data

I have a script that installs Remote Desktop Services on remote machines (from the DC).

I'm now at the phase where I check if RDS installed on the connection broker (server) and connection host (server).

I want to use invoke-command since a remote powershell session seemed too complicated.

This is the code I have:

```
$res = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "testpc.eil.local" -ScriptBlock {
if((Get-WindowsFeature -Name "Remote-Desktop-Services").Installed -eq 1)
{
   #i need this output (true or false or a string)
}
else
{
     #i need this output (true or false or a string)
}
}


Write-Host $res
```

But my question is, how do I encapsulate the output of the scriptblock in the invoke-command in a variable that the DC can access? I'm trying to write away if RDS is succesfully installed or failed to a log-file

How do we encapsulate the output of the function and pass it to the machine who's running it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally for powershell to return something from a command\function, you want to produce any kind of output. So just "bla-bla" inside your code will return "bla-bla" to the caller. With that your case simplified:

```
$res = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "testpc.eil.local" -ScriptBlock {
    (Get-WindowsFeature -Name "Remote-Desktop-Services").Installed
}

do something with $res here
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's weird that your method works but mine doesn't hehe!

Comment: just like I said, yours doesn't because you don't actually OUTPUT anything. You need to OUTPUT stuff to have something to capture

Comment: Okay but I was wondering why I couldn't just write `Write-Host "Installed!"` When I included it in my first script. (if test) but if I understand you correctly, it's because it's gets printed in the 'window' of the remote server and not the one from the DC?

Comment: yeah, don't use `write-host`, generally speaking, its messed up, use `write-output`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've understood it thanks to your explanation